# Can't borrow data as a '&' reference as mutable

Tags: rust

I have this function that looks like this

Install Magic-Crypt to reproduce the error.

```
magic-crypt = "3.1.10"
```

Import the following: `pub use magic_crypt::{new_magic_crypt, MagicCryptTrait, MagicCryptError};`

Here is the function

```
pub fn magic_decrypt(mut phrase: &String, hash: &String, decrypt: String) -> Option<Result<String, MagicCryptError>> {
    println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut phrase).expect("Failed to read line");
    if &hash_string(&phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string()) == hash {
        println!("Success, you've entered the correct phrase, decrypting...");
        return Some(new_magic_crypt!(phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string(), 256).decrypt_base64_to_string(&decrypt));
    } else {
        println!("Failed to enter the correct phrase, please try again.");
        while &hash_string(&phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string()) != hash {
            println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
            std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut phrase).expect("Failed to read line");
            let _phrase = phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string();
        }
        return None;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get these errors (despite me setting the variable as mutable)

```
    error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in a `&` reference as mutable
  --> crypto/crypto.rs:78:40
   |
78 |             std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut phrase).expect("Failed to read line");
   |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

[image]

What can I do to fix this? If this question is bad, please tell me as well, thanks!

Comment: `phrase` must be marked as a mutable reference too. In your arguments `&mut phrase`

Comment: `hash_string` function not found

Comment: your method it is wrong? it should be `phrase: &mut String,` and not `mut phrase: &String`. Looks like also a parser error?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Parser error? `mut phrase: &String` is perfectly valid, it just doesn't fit the `&mut phrase` later.

Comment: @Finomnis I missed this sorry https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2sjicp/comment/cnq3esc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mut phrase: &String` means that the `phrase` variable is a mutable object that references an immutable string. What you probably tried to do is `phrase: &mut String`, which is an immutable variable that references a mutable string.
You can then also remove the `&mut` reborrow at the `read_line` function call.

```rust
pub fn magic_decrypt(phrase: &mut String, hash: &String, decrypt: String) -> Option<Result<String, MagicCryptError>> {
    println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
    std::io::stdin().read_line(phrase).expect("Failed to read line");
    if &hash_string(&phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string()) == hash {
        println!("Success, you've entered the correct phrase, decrypting...");
        return Some(new_magic_crypt!(phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string(), 256).decrypt_base64_to_string(&decrypt));
    } else {
        println!("Failed to enter the correct phrase, please try again.");
        while &hash_string(&phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string()) != hash {
            println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
            std::io::stdin().read_line(phrase).expect("Failed to read line");
            let _phrase = phrase.replace("\r", "").clone().to_string();
        }
        return None;
    }
}
```

---

Further problems I detected:

- `.replace()` already returns a `String`, `.clone()` on it creates the same `String` again, and `to_string()` yet again creates the same `String`. Just leave out the entire `.clone().to_string()`.
- use `&str` instead of `&String` in your arguments as it is a strict superset of it. This also eliminates all the `&` borrows you use to compare `String` with `&String`, as `String` is directly comparable with `&str`.
- the `let _phrase = phrase.replace(...)` does nothing.
- `return` statements in Rust at the end of a `{}` are not necessary, you can directly write `None` instead of `return None;`.
- if you replace a single character, it is recommended to specify it as a char instead of a string (`'\r'` instead of `"\r"`).
- You always return `None` if you enter the `else` case, even if a correct phrase was entered. This one probably requires structural changes in your `if`/`while` constructs.
- Your code isn't formatted with `cargo fmt`. I recommend enabling auto-format.

Some of those fixes come from `cargo clippy`, which I can recommend to run from time to time as it gives valuable insights for improving your code quality.

Here I fixed some of those.

```rust
pub fn magic_decrypt(
    phrase: &mut String,
    hash: &str,
    decrypt: &str,
) -> Option<Result<String, MagicCryptError>> {
    println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(phrase)
        .expect("Failed to read line");
    if hash_string(&phrase.replace('\r', "")) == hash {
        println!("Success, you've entered the correct phrase, decrypting...");
        Some(new_magic_crypt!(phrase.replace('\r', ""), 256).decrypt_base64_to_string(decrypt))
    } else {
        println!("Failed to enter the correct phrase, please try again.");
        while hash_string(&phrase.replace('\r', "")) != hash {
            println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
            std::io::stdin()
                .read_line(phrase)
                .expect("Failed to read line");
            let _phrase = phrase.replace('\r', "");
        }
        None
    }
}
```

---

The last point I mentioned, that you always return `None` in your `else` case, seems to indicate that your `if`/`while` layout is incorrect.

This is just a wild guess, but I assume you attempted to write something like this:

```rust
pub fn magic_decrypt(
    phrase: &mut String,
    hash: &str,
    decrypt: &str,
) -> Result<String, MagicCryptError> {
    println!("Please insert your decryption phrase: ");
    loop {
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(phrase)
            .expect("Failed to read line");
        *phrase = phrase.trim_end().to_string();
        if hash_string(phrase) == hash {
            println!("Success, you've entered the correct phrase, decrypting...");
            break new_magic_crypt!(hash, 256).decrypt_base64_to_string(decrypt);
        } else {
            println!("Failed to enter the correct phrase, please try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

A last point I would like to mention because it's quite important: If you use *hashing* for storing passwords, it's crucial that you use [*salting*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983).

Comment: Thank you so, so much! Some of the code was written by Copilot, that's why,

Comment: Also, I know about the salting thing but I don't think that I need it as it is supposed to be used as a Keystore file. The person shouldn't be giving their Keystore anyways.

Comment: Hashes aren't for when they intentionally give their keystore away. They are for when they get stolen. If you "don't want to give them away" you could also store them in plaintext in the first place; so if you use hashes, use salted hashes. That's at least my two cents ;)

Comment: It's even worse; as you store both the encrypted data and the hashes on your device, the hashes could be used to actually decrypt the data with rainbow table attacks. You definitely don't want your hashes to carry enough information to decrypt your data.

Comment: Maybe but I don't think hash tables will be too practical to try in my software.

Comment: Can't a person just do a rainbow table attack, and then combine it with your salt?

Comment: The whole point of a rainbow table is that you can spend immense computational power *once* to compute inverted hashes and then use it as an indexed lookup to retrieve the original password from the hash. If you use a salt, you would have to compute a separate rainbow table for every salt, which is the equivalent of a bruteforce attack.
Read the post I linked in my answer, it describes why and how to use salts very well.

Comment: So could the salt be viewable along with the salted hash and the ciphertext and still be much, much safer?

Comment: Yeah, correct. You store the salt, the salted hash and the ciphertext. Read the link I posted, though. There are good libraries for password hashing, it's not advised to implement that manually. They are quite simple to use.

Comment: Can't someone just do a table attack, then combine it w/ the salt?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of the salt :) again, read the article I linked :) it's all described there